ApiPlatform Nested Object in DTO in GraphQL
I want using DTO
This my code.
<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform\DTO;

class RequestDto
{
    public ?string $note = null;

    /**
     * @var UserDto
     */
    public UserDto $user;
}

<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform\DTO;


class UserDto
{
    public string $name;
}

#[ApiPlatform\ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new ApiPlatform\Post(input: RequestDTO::class, processor: RequestProcessor::class),
    ],
    graphQlOperations: [
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Query(),
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Mutation(
            name: 'create',
            input: RequestDTO::class,
            processor: RequestProcessor::class,
        ),
    ],
)]
class Request {
...

If I using rest api schema like this
{
  "note": "string",
  "user": {
    "name": "string"
  }
}

but if I using GraphQl schema:
note: String
clientMutationId: String

I get error
Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: \"App\\ApiPlatform\\DTO\\RequestDTO\" vs \"App\\ApiPlatform\\DTO\\RequestDto\

Its bug? or I cant using DTO with GraphQL?
My system:

symfony 7.1.6
api-platform 4.0.10
php 8.3.13
MacOS


The problem is related to the case sensitivity of PHP class names and how they are treated in different contexts by GraphQL and REST API when working with DTOs in API Platform.
In your example, the class RequestDto is referred with different casing:
In GraphQL operations, it is referred to as RequestDTO.
However, the real class is named requestDto (lowercase "Dto").
